# How to select 50 most occurring values out of 3000 values to makes histogram?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset with 1 column that contains 3000 unique names. A sample of dataset is as follows:

```
SPEAKER:
dwayne-bohac
scott-surovell
barack-obama
blog-posting
charlie-crist
```

the number of unique values:

```
print(trainer['SPEAKER'].nunique())
```

output:

```
2915
```

the value count:

```
print(trainer['SPEAKER'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False))
```

output:

```
barack-obama       491
donald-trump       274
hillary-clinton    239
mitt-romney        179
scott-walker       150
                  ... 
sam-rashid           1
```

I want to select 50 of the most occurring names to make the histogram. Is there a built in functionality in panda library? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you've _already ordered your data_, you can look for "select first n rows of dataframe" and discover [`.head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `head` and `plot.bar`:

```
(trainer['SPEAKER']
        .value_counts()
        .sort_values(ascending=False)
        .head(50)
        .plot.bar()
)
```

Comment: I print the code you posted. I am not getting bar plot output. I get following output: AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77). how can i use plt.show() with your code.